# Getting data from JSON and comparing at Login

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have made a JSON webservice which has a list of userID and passwords.I want to get the userID and password checked/compared on the loginscreen of submit button of my ionic project only when details match I should be logged in to my next page  or else my access should be denied.
Im very new to angularjs i need the code for this requirement.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what did you do, please post your code

Comment: I havnt started coded anything as yet..I thought if anyone could explain this in brief wether this kind of situation is possible or no

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code snippet what exactly your needs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       
        
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("sampleApp",[]);
            app.controller("MainController",["memberListService","$scope", function (memberListService,$scope) {
                $scope.login = function () {
                    
                    var state = false;
                    var data = memberListService.getList;
                    angular.forEach(data, function (ele) {
                        console.log(ele);
                        if($scope.user.name == ele.user && $scope.user.password == ele.pass){
                         state = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if(state){
                        alert('user found')
                    }else{
                        alert('user not found')
                    }
                }
               
            }]);
            
            app.service('memberListService', function () {
                    this.getList = [
                        {
                            user: "user1", pass: "pass1"
                        },
                        {
                            user: "user2", pass: "pass2"
                        }
                    ]

                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">
        <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
            <form name="clientLogin">
                

                
                    <input ng-model="user.name" name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                    
               
                    
                    <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-required="true" name="userPassword" autocomplete="off">
                   
                

                <button type="button" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```